# O objeto 'connection' pode ser descartado mais de uma vez no método

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, conexão

Segue o código:

```
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    string query = "UPDATE Table SET Status = 'C' WHERE Id = @Num";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Num", SqlDbType.Int).Value = model.Numero;
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Page", "Account");
}
```

Recebo um aviso na listas de erros:

> CA2202: O objeto 'connection' pode ser descartado mais de uma vez no método
>   'AccountController.Index(ViewModel, string)'. Para evitar a geração de
>   System.ObjectDisposedException, não chame Dispose mais de uma vez em
>   um objeto.

Alguma solução?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta tirar o fechamento explícito da conexão, afinal está fazendo certo com o `using` que vai fechar a conexão.

```
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
    var query = "UPDATE Table SET Status = 'C' WHERE Id = @Num";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)) {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Num", SqlDbType.Int).Value = model.Numero;
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Page", "Account");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DataBase/CloseConnection.cs).