# Qual o problema com o meu Update?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Bom dia.

Sou iniciante e estou com problemas no meu Update.
Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado.

```
    public string Update(Usuario usuario)
    {
        var sql = new StringBuilder();

        sql.Append("UPDATE TBUSU SET " + Environment.NewLine);

        sql.Append($" SENHA     = '{usuario.Senha}' ");
        sql.Append($" ,EMAIL    = '{usuario.Email}' ");
        sql.Append($" ,TELEFONE = {usuario.Telefone} ");
        sql.Append($" ,STATUS   = '{(int)usuario.Status}' ");
        sql.Append($" ,FUNCAO   = '{(int)usuario.Funcao}' ");
        sql.Append("   WHERE    " + Environment.NewLine);
        sql.Append($"  NOME     = '{usuario.Nome}' ");


        var ret = Conexao.ExecutarComando(sql.ToString());

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Não sei se é necessário realmente o uso de aspas, mas no telefone você nao utilizou, por exemplo. Você ao invés de usar `var ret` pode usar diretamente `return Conexao.ExecutarComando(sql.ToString());`. Tente ver a saída de sql.ToString() também e veja como está a string.

Comment: Muita coisa, principalmente um sério problema de segurança. O correto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202903/101 Veja tb https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183975/101

Comment: Problemas tem vários, como mencionado pelo Maniero... Mas qual é o erro que você está recebendo?

Comment: Ele não está atualizando. Não mostra o erro.

Comment: Então... pode ser o seu `ExecutarComando()` ou simplesmente não está encontrando nenhum usuário como nome informado.

Comment: Edite a pergunta apresentando o código alterado com as recomendações do Maniero